# array .any? or .empty? conundrum in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm attempting to check if there is anything at all in an array, and I'm confused about the results.

```
markets.any? do |m|
    m["market"]["name"] == "Atlanta"
end.should be_true
```

Returns `You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!, You might have expected an instance of Array.`

But

```
markets.empty? do |m|
    m["market"]["name"] == "Atlanta"
end.should be_false
```

Doesn't error. But it seems backwards to me, because I want to test for true, not false. And I don't get why .any? thinks it's nill. BTW, there are 3 items in the array, and none are nil.

Comment: how your markets array look like? Is it having any nil object?

Comment: [{"name":"Atlanta","created_at":"2011-11-18T15:49:49Z","updated_at":"2011-11-18T15:49:49Z","id":38}]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per your comment, the market key is not present in hash, try following

```
markets.any? do |m|
    m["name"] == "Atlanta"
end.should be_true
```

Comment: Naren, that did the trick. In your opinion, which is the better approach. Or is it just a personal preference since both work?

Comment: use any? method, I'm not sure about the empty? because in ruby(1.9.3) empty? does not take any parameter and as per your code the given block is never executed. you are getting false because the array is not empty.
any? is better if you want to check if any element in array is having name=='Atlanta'

Answer (score 0):

present? may be what you're looking for...

```
markets.present? do |m|
    m["name"] == "Atlanta"
end.should be_true
```